# How to erase flash memory (SD card)?

Tags: memory, embedded, sd-card, erase

I am developing embedded system that writes to SD card.
As you all know, write access is faster if flash is pre-erased.
Is there any easy way to erase flash memory in windows?
Thanks,
Yony.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The flash memory on an SD card is managed by an on-card controller, you do not have the level of control to directly erase the NAND flash itself.

However when doing a multi-block write (CMD25) you can precede it with a pre-erase command (ACMD23) to pre-erase the blocks; this is significantly faster.  However if you specify a pre-erase then terminate the subsequent write, the content of the unwritten blocks is undefined according to the specification.  Also pre-erasure is supported only on SD cards, not MMC cards.  The details are in the [SD Specifications Part 1 Physical Layer Simplified Specification](http://www.sdcard.org/developers/tech/sdcard/pls/Simplified_Physical_Layer_Spec.pdf)

Comment: Thanks. There is also an Erase command that do the work...

Comment: Supposedly, SanDisk's [SD Formatter](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/) can be used for this.